# wrong url with html.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, vb.net-2010

I was made paging system. Everything is OK.
After click 2nd page all homepage links changing.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home page", "Index", "Home") //This is standard routing without values.
```

I was added paging links to end of page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("2", "Index", "Home", New With {.id = 2}, Nothing) //This works good too.
```

My problem is when I click to 2nd or more page (e.g : www.site.com/Home/Index/2) my all homepage links converting to

```
<a href="/Home/Index/2">Home page</a>
```

same this.
How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: what is the current url that you are on that you are having a problem with?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Home page", "Index", "Home") commands, generates <a href="/Home/Index/2">Home page</a> same this values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on the 2nd page the `{.id = 2}` will be part of your RouteData. And because your routing probably looks like this: (in Gloabal.asax)

```
 routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

ASP.NET MVC will use this route for the generated links. So it will include Id = 2. To fix this you need to explicitly override it when it's not needed:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home page", "Index", "Home", New With {.id = ""}, Nothing)
```